# How can I set a Python variable in a SQLAlchemy update query?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask API endpoint that receives the following JSON:

```
{
  "domain": "example.com",
  "setting": {
    "key": "frequency",
    "value": 100
  }
}
```

The value of `['setting']['key']` is set to `frequency` above, but there are going to be dozens of potential values. Instead of constructing a giant if...elif statement that examines the value of `['setting']['key']`, I tried to do this:

```py
json_data = request.get_json()

domain = json_data['domain']
setting_key = json_data['setting']['key']
setting_value = json_data['setting']['value']

sql_domains = Domains.query.filter_by(domain=domain).first()
sql_domains.setting_key = setting_value
#           ^^^^^^^^^^^

db.session.commit()
```

As I have highlighted with arrows in the code, I am unable to set the SQLAlchemy key to my custom variable (`setting_key`). No error messages are returned, but the value in my database is not updated.

## EDIT: SOLVED

Figured it out. Changed the JSON:

```
{
    "domain": "example.com",
    "settings": {
        "frequency": 1000
    }
}
```

And the code:

```py
for key, value in json_data['settings'].items():
    setattr(sql_domains, key, value)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: So you want to do `sql_domains.setting_key = ...` instead of `sql_domains.frequency = ...` ?

Comment: Yes, correct! That why I don't have to know the target setting @GordThompson